# opendiff not getting launched after `git mergetool`

Tags: command-line, xcode, git, macos

When I try to do a `git mergetool` (after getting a merge conflict), I get that the merge.tool is not configured..., and

```
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff):
```

After pressing return, I however see the following:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'opendiff' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Note that I have Xcode downloaded, and it does have FileMerge in `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Applications/FileMerge`.

What is happening here? And how to launch opendiff when I summon `git mergetool`?

---

Actually, running `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/11953295)) solved the issue. Now the **question** is: How did this work? FileMerge doesn't seem to be there in `.../Developer`, only in `.../Applications/`.